# Duplicate controls on Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am having this issue where when I add a control to my project it displays two of the same control. I tried just deleting the original form and creating a new project altogether. I still get the same result. This happens in Visual Studio 2010 both Ultimate and Premium. Any Ideas? I never seen this behavior before.

[image: Form]

Comment: Does it appear twice in your .designer file?

Comment: Did you call InitializeComponents 2 times?

Comment: @RezaAghaei No the IntializeComponent() only gets called in the Form_Load method

Comment: @Mort No it only has just one instance of the ribbon control in the FormMain.vb and designer.

Comment: And Also one time in constructor. You don't need to call it in form load.

Comment: Does this happen if you add other types of controls, like a command button?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yeah I just removed the Initalize component from the form_load and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OP: The `IntializeComponent()` only gets called in the `Form_Load` method

In a Visual Basic project, the default form constructor that calls `InitializeComponent` does't show, but it really executes.

You don't need to call `IntializeComponent()` in `Form_Load`.

**So it seems the problem is you have called `InitializeComponent` 2 times.**

The result is obvious for docked controls, but for other controls because the second instance is completely in the same location and size of first instance, you can't see an obvious symptom. But for docked controls, because location doesn't have any impact, you will see the result obviously.

Comment: More generally, you want to avoid doing stuff like this in `Form_Load`. Anything that *can* be done in the constructor *should* be done in the constructor.